# Three.js Mirror reflection issue

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, three.js

I am using Three.js Mirror class to reflect a ring mesh in my scene and the reflection has strange artifacts in it.

This is the relevant code:

```
verticalMirror = new THREE.Mirror( renderer, camera, { clipBias: 0.003, textureWidth: 512, textureHeight: 512, color:0xdddddd} );

var verticalMirrorMesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 300, 300 ), verticalMirror.material );
verticalMirrorMesh.add( verticalMirror );
verticalMirrorMesh.position.y = 0;
verticalMirrorMesh.position.z = -10;
editor.scene.add( verticalMirrorMesh );

function render () {
   renderer.clear();
   verticalMirror.render();
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

In the center the reflection looks more or less ok, but on the sides it's stretched to the edges of the mirror. Please see the images below.

[image: Zoomed out, view from the right]

[image: Zoomed in, view from the left]

I've researched other posts on mirroring in Three.js and seem to follow what they are suggesting. What am I still doing wrong? Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you,
Anton.

Comment: So it looks like THREE.Mirror requires a Perspective camera and doesn't play well with Orthographic camera...

Comment: It is important that you provide _all_ the relevant information in your post.